# Problems while opening Jupyter Notebook in the browser

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, windows-8.1

I had anaconda installed in on my Windows 8.1. Yesterday I had to do some work with web development and I installed *Brackets* on my Windows. After that when I opened JupyterNotebook, it opened in Brackets.
To solve the issue I uninstalled *Brackets* and opened Jupyter Notebook again but it didn't open afterwards.

I then checked my Task Manager to observe what was wrong and I saw that the Jupyter Notebook is open in some other place than the browser but it is not visible: [image: JupyterNotebook]

I had also tried reinstalling anaconda but even this didn't work.
Will be very thankful if anyone provides a good solution for this.

Some screenshots are attached that might be helpful: [image: Task Manager]

Comment: You start Jupter by command `jupyter notebook` in cmd?

Comment: Did you try to copy (`ctrl shift c`) and paste (`ctrl v`) the `url` into the browser to see if it opened? Also try restarting the computer.

Comment: @ningchen I tried both wats. I tried to launch it from the graphical interface of anaconda and the anaconda prompt. Both ways didn't work. However, I didn't tried from cmd. After reading your comment i tried writing this command in cmd and it show "Didn't recognize this as internal or external command"

Comment: @bob1 Yes I tried to restart the laptop but even this didn't work. However, I didn't tried copying the url. I can only copy the url when the notebook is opened somewhere. In this case, I don't have access to the url which I might copy.

Comment: copy this url "http://localhost:8889/?token=899a115....." from cmd, and paste it into your browser.

Comment: Thanks @bob1. At first it didn't work. But than I opened this url and tried opening the notebook from the **anaconda prompt** and it worked. Appreciate your timely response.